# Cannot connect to mysqli. Error no 2005

Tags: php, mysqli

I have developed a simple web site on local (using XAMPP) accessing a database and retrieving & displaying data.

When I moved the site to the actual server, I started getting errors reşated to database access.

I tried to simplify the code to debug. I noticed that the error code is 2005. I could not find very descriptive information on the net but I think it means something like server name is not recognized. I am not sure and I need help

The extract from the javascript calling the .php file is :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "test.php"
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("Returned FAIL");
      })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        console.log('SUCCESS : ' + msg);
    });
});
```

And the PHP code is :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
echo 'CONNx : <' . $conn . '>';
```

The console log received from the PHP code is:

SUCCESS : Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.
Debugging errno: 2005

That means it does fall into .fail{} and returns into .done{}

I have been trying to understand the problem. I have found suggestions to check the servername, username and password. They are correct.

Well the error is related to the servername as even if I type in a wrong username, still the same error pops up.

I tried both "localhost", "localhost:3306" and "www.actualhostname.com" for server name.

I suspect it may come out to be a very simple solution but I am stuck and cannot progress. I need help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` too.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. Try to use search before asking a question.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I actually did use search and came across the answer mentioned. None of the suggestions there helped. That is why I wanted to place a question. I do not know how I can differentiate my question from the previous one as it describes the problem as is.